# SharePoint JQuery GetUserLoginFromEmail

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, webservices-client

Could someone provide an an example of how to call the SharePoint WebService, "GetUserLoginFromEmail"?

Thanks!

Comment: what exacly do you want? an ajax call?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
    var xml = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">';
    xml += '  <soap:Body>';
    xml += '    <GetUserLoginFromEmail xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/">';
    xml += '      <emailXml><Users><User Email="somename@email.com"/></Users></emailXml>';
    xml += '    </GetUserLoginFromEmail>';
    xml += '  </soap:Body>';
    xml += '</soap:Envelope>';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx',
    dataType: 'xml',
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    data: xml,
    success: function(data) {
      // data is here. You can use .attr("Attribute") to get, well, attributes!
      console.log($(data).find("User"));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend getting the jQuery Library for SharePoint Web Services (SPServices) from CodePlex: http://spservices.codeplex.com
It will give you a wrapper for that call and every other SharePoint web service there is.